# Eigenvalues and Corresponding Eigenspace Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, visualization

Could someone describe the eigenvalues of $ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1   \\
-1 & 2 
 \end{array} \right) $, as well as the bases of the corresponding eigenspaces?

I received eigenvalues of $ \lambda = 2+i, 2-i$. And $ E_{2+i} = \operatorname{span}\{[1,i]^T\}$ and $E_{2-i} = \operatorname{span}\{ [1,-i]^T\}$. It also wants me to illustrate the action of $A$ on eigenvectors. How would I do so?

Are these solutions correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct except the eigenvectors are
$$
E_{2+i} = (1,i)^t\\
E_{2-i} = (1,-i)^t
$$

The action of $A$ on eigenvalue $E_\lambda$ is to multiply it by $\lambda$

Comment: This is what I meant, my apologies. & Yes, but how do I draw this geometrically? It asks for a visual depiction.

Comment: Well, the vectors are complex, so you have to draw it in 4 dimensions. For problems like this, you work with just the real part and the imaginary part of the eigenvector. In each case, the vector gets rotated by an angle and scaled. Just do the math to see what the angle is and the scaling is. Hint: $|\lambda| = \sqrt{5}$ and $\angle \lambda = \atan{1/2}$.

Comment: you want me to draw it with x real y imaginary? or two separate graphs? does this just mean that it rotates the vector 26.57 degree and scales it by $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: One graph. The real part is $(1,0)^t$. The action of $A$ results in $(2,-1)$. This is rotating clockwise by $\arctan(1/2)$ or a rotation of $\arctan(-1/2)$. Do the same for the imaginary part: $(0,1)^t$.

Comment: So I'd draw one real graph, and one imaginary graph? I'm not quite seeing what it is you're saying. Doesn't it send the imaginary part to 0?

Comment: There is **no** imaginary graph. You are dealing with real vectors. I think you are not understanding what is needed. Draw some vector in the plane say $(3,5)^t$. This is the vector from (0,0) to (3,5) on the graph paper. Now calculate A times this vector. You get $(11, 7)^t$. This is the result of the action of the matrix $A$ on the vector $(3,5)^t$. Do the same for the vectors $(1,0)^t$ and $(0,1)^t$ and see what happens. I suggest you do it on a graph paper to see what happens (or draw it to scale).

Comment: naturally it sends $(1,0)^T \to (2,-1)^T$, $(0,1)^T \to (1,2)^T$, and $(0,-1)^T \to (-1,-2)$^T. So what do I label each vector as?

Comment: If you label them $u_1$ and $u_2$, then label them $A u_1$ and $A u_2$. You do not need both $(0,1)^T$ and $(0,-1)^T$.